# Spliting Curved Polygon with various length of lines using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

To split the curved polygon (river polygon) with various length of lines while keeping the original line position, I tried the procedure as bellow.

[image]

1. extend the lines using `'qgis:extendlines'`

[image]

2. intersect the lines with polygon using `'qgis:intersection'`

[image]

However, non-intended extended lines appeared compared to original lines (lines extending from a curved river), so I selected the extended lines based on original lines using `'native:extractbylocation'` with 'overlap'.  However, no features were selected after the `'native:extractbylocation`'

Can I get the features overlapped with original lines ?

This is my pyqgis script.

```
# hn_ln is original line layers
# hn_pg is polygon to be cut

output_line0 = processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:extendlines', {'INPUT':hn_ln, 'START_DISTANCE':2000, 'END_DISTANCE':2000, 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})

output_line1 = processing.runAndLoadResults('qgis:intersection', {'INPUT':output_line0['OUTPUT'], 'OVERLAY':hn_pg,  'INPUT_FIELDS':[], 'OVERLAY_FIELDS':[],'OUTPUT':'memory:'})

output_line3 = processing.runAndLoadResults('native:extractbylocation', {'INPUT':output_line2['OUTPUT'], 'PREDICATE':['5'], 'INTERSECT':hn_ln, 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})
```